# How Add values to var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Values>()

Tags: c#, .net

I created a `public struct Values` that has `public string value1`and `public string value2`.

```
public struct Values
{
   public string header;
   public string type;
}
```

My dictionary:

```
var myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, Values>();
```

Question: How do I add two values for each key?

```
while (true)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < end i++)
   {
        myDictionary.Add(i, value1 , value2);
   }
}
```

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre this actually worked. So for **key** that equals to "1" I will have two values of `struct Values`? Am i understanding right?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Comment: Use a `Dictionary<int, List<Values>>`

Comment: @JaydipJ, with self declared `structure` will i be able to do concatenation `String.Join()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *generate* dictionary, you can try using *Linq*:

```
 var myDictionary = Enumerable 
   .Range(0, end)
   .Select(i => new {
      key = i,
      value = new Values() {
        header = HeaderFromIndex(i), //TODO: implement this
        type = TypeFromIndex(i)      //TODO: implement this 
      }})
   .ToDictionary(item => item.key, item => item.value);
```

In case you want to add items into *existing* dictionary:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < end; ++i)
   myDictionary.Add(i, new Values() {
     header = HeaderFromIndex(i), //TODO: implement this
     type = TypeFromIndex(i)      //TODO: implement this 
   });
```

Please notice, that in any case dictionary holds *pairs*: `{key, value}`; so if you want to have *two* items as values for the corresponding key, you have to *organize* the values into a class `new Values() {header = ..., type = ...}` in your case

Comment: will i be able to do concatenation using `String.Join()` ? For example using only `header` value of `Values` dictionary?

Comment: @TheOneAndOnlyNoobofCSharp: yes, e.g. if you want to concatenate all `header` values you can put `string result = string.Join(", ", myDictionary.Select(pair => pair.Value.header));`

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: Aren't we looking at `Values` containing `Value1` and `Value2`, where each of them internally contains header and type.

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The idea was to have `Dictionary` that would have `int key` and for each `key` I wanted to have two values of `List` which are `header` and `type`

Answer (score 1):

If I get the question correctly, you have to initialize a Values object and than add this one to your dictionary. Like this:

```
while (true) {
    for (int i = 0; i < end i++) {
        Values tmp_values;
        tmp_values.header = "blabla";
        tmp_values.type = "blabla type";

        myDictionary.Add(i, tmp_values);
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense decent example

Comment: Aren't we looking at `Values` containing `Value1` and `Value2`, where each of them internally contains header and type.